# Python: [Errno 2] No such file or directory in V.S. Code on Mac

Tags: python

I have written the following code in my OpenCV Project in python in V.S. Code on Mac:-

```
import os
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np

people = ['Name_1', 'Name_2', 'Name_3', 'Name_4', 'Name_5']

dir = '/Users/john/OpenCV_Python/People'

def create_train():
    for person in people:
      path = os.path.join(dir,person)
```

But, when I run the code, I am getting the following error:

```
[Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

Any suggestions on what's wrong with my dir (Directory variable) or any other changes to resolve this issue? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet, so this is not an answer. Have you tried with `dir = '~/OpenCV_Python/People'`? are  you sure the program has the right permissions to access to your files?

Comment: Thanks for thr reply! Yes, I have tried that, but still doesn't work. Yes, it has the access to my files!

Comment: Well, of course it must be a problem in the dir and as I don't use Mac I don't know how to fix if, sorry